# Zend CRUD Data Mapper Example?

Tags: zend-framework, datamapper, crud

Can anyone point or sketch a VERY BASIC data Mapper Example on CRUD operations, considering that, we have at least two tables related with a foreign key ?

Just trying to follow (and adapt) the quick-start guide with no success so far, so I was wondering if someone could explain a CRUD application using data mapper, better.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ ?

Comment: @Marcin - Yes. I was on my way to follow it and I actually read it until the end but. Immo, it misses a very common and important step. Table relations. That tutorial seems a good to go on those cases where you have 1:1 relations between your model class and your tables. Actually my question could also be: How to adapt akrabat.com tutorial and allow us, from the structure there created to work with table relations. That's the key point that I'm missing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've recently followed along with this one which was great - up to a point: http://survivethedeepend.com/

And there's a few others out there that give this one a nod as inspiration. However, it's not complete and the biggest problem is that it doesn't cover how to retrieve objects by non-ID selection criteria.

That question is actually why I just signed up. :)

Good luck, please let me know if you find a good and complete resource!